# Behavior of this RC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

**note:** This may be a homework question but I am not asking anyone to give me the answers as I already have them: Im only looking for an explanation for what's actually going on.

**Question: once the capacitors are charged, the switch is moved to position Y. State what happens to the p.d across Capacitor P and Q**

[image]

TO some extent, I understand that the capacitor P, with the help of the new path for the charges, will discharge itself. But I really dont get why all of the p.d must be across Q, and none of it across the resistor.

Also, other than the explanation of the mechanism using laws of electrostatics, is there any way to predict the p.d s in the steady state directly using circuit equations? I really don't know how resistors and capacitors work together in RC circuits/

Comment: I am a high school student but think that thevenin and norton theorems might have an easier approach

Comment: I am a high school student too. Those theorems aren't in our syllabus unfortunately. Moreover, this is a question from a CIE past paper, so Im expected to answer using basic knowlege of capacitors and electrostatics.

Comment: Can we assume the thing just above the upper left battery is Extraneous  Mark?

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH then unfortunately at our level you have to solve using normal definition of capacitors and Kirchoff's laws

Comment: @BobD yes, its from an erasor. Sorry about that

Comment: @PranavAggarwal How exactly using the kirchhoff's laws would you arrive at the steady state p.d s across each component?

Comment: the voltages across each component continuously change before coming constant to 9V,0V, 0V

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116524/discussion-between-overwootch-and-pranav-aggarwal).

Comment: Once the resistor is in the circuit, as long as there’s voltage across it, it will draw current.  Ask yourself where this current will come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: once the capacitors are charged, the switch is moved to
> position Y. State what happens to the p.d across Capacitor P and Q

The instant after switching occurs, assuming ideal capacitors, the p.d. across capacitors P and Q will be the same as the p.d. across these capacitors the instant before switching occurs. The reasons are as follows:

The relationship between capacitor voltage, current and capacitance is given by

$$V=\frac{Q}{C}$$

So for a given capacitance $C$, the voltage across the capacitor is proportional to the net charge $Q$ on each plate of the capacitor (which are equal in magnitude and opposite in polarity). This means charge must be moved from one plate to the other to change the net charge on each plate and the voltage. That requires current and time according to

$$v(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int i(t)dt+V_i$$

> TO some extent, I understand that the capacitor P, with the help of
> the new path for the charges, will discharge itself. But I really dont
> get why all of the p.d must be across Q, and none of it across the
> resistor.

Under steady state conditions in a dc circuit, ideal capacitors look like open circuits and no current can flow to the capacitor. The relationship between capacitor current and voltage is

$$i(t)=C\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$

Under steady state conditions voltages in a dc circuit are not changing in time. Therefore $dv(t)/dt=0$ and $i(t)=0$. Therefore when the switch is in position Y for a long time, there is no current flowing in the series circuit of capacitor Q and resistor R. If there is no current flowing through resistor R then the p.d. across resistor R is zero. Since capacitor P is in parallel with resistor R, there is no p.d. across capacitor P. That, in turn, means all the voltage of the two batteries is across capacitor Q.

> Also, other than the explanation of the mechanism using laws of
> electrostatics, is there any way to predict the p.d s in the steady
> state directly using circuit equations? I really don't know how
> resistors and capacitors work together in RC circuits

You can predict the voltage and current for an ideal capacitor using the last two equations I gave you. When you analyzed dc circuits with capacitors (and/or inductors) you need to separate the analysis into different time periods, using these steps:

1. Steady state conditions prior to a switching event. Under these conditions all ideal capacitors look like open circuits because voltages are not changing and current to a capacitor is zero per the third equation above.
2. Switching event time t=0. The instant after switching the voltages across all capacitors are the same as they were the instant before switching. The reason is you can't change the voltage across an ideal capacitor in zero time, per the second equation above. It takes time and current to change the charge Q, and thus the voltage V in the first equation above.
3. The transient period t=0 to t=∞ (steady state). During this period voltages and currents are changing as capacitors charge and/or discharge. You can look up the equations covering these changes for dc RC circuits.
4. Resumption of steady state conditions (t=∞). Reapply step 1 with the switch in the new position.

Hope these help you.

Comment: I get how a capacitor can be considered as an open circuit once fully charged, however I was not aware that this tiny fact could actually be a useful problem solving tool. Thankyou so much

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH You can use the same steps to evaluate ideal inductors in dc circuits.  The difference is an ideal inductor looks like a short circuit under steady state conditions and you can't change the current in an inductor in zero time, i.e., the current in an inductor is the same the instant before and instant after switching.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the capacitors all have the same capacitance, when the switch is in position, x, the charge from the lower plate of the upper capacitor is shared equally between capacitors, P, and , T. Then each of those will display half the voltage of the upper capacitor.  When the switch is thrown to, y, the only immediate change will be current through the resistor. Part of this comes from capacitor, P, which over time discharges itself through the resistor until both of them is at zero volts.  As the voltage on the resistor drops, the voltage on the upper capacitor must increase, and this requires some charge flow  from the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few points that should get you on track.

From the fundamental formula of the capacitor, $Q=CV$, you know that the voltage across a capacitor is inversely proportional to C.

Capacitors in parallel add so that the resulting capacitance is $C_Eq=C_1+C_2$.

Capacitors in series (assuming initially uncharged) will accumulate the same charge, $Q$, since they are experiencing the same $dq/dt$ current flow.  Regardless of their capacitance value.

The voltage across each capacitor in a series connection of capacitors (assuming initially uncharged before battery applied) will be inversely proportional to their capacitance value.

There must be a difference of potential between the battery and the capacitor for current to flow from the battery.  Once a capacitor has been charged to the point that its voltage exactly opposes the battery, no current flows.

Comment: I am aware of all these rules but the addition of that resistor changes everything, doesn't it?

Comment: The resistor will draw current flow if it experiences a voltage across its terminals.Think about the 2 places this current can come from and I think you will deduce the end result for both capacitors (“Q” and “P”).

Comment: Looks good to me.